# Dynamic inference of type from String value in java

Tags: string, types, jackson, inference

I have a parameter of type object in my endpoint method. I want jackson to be able to convert it to int if it sees "25" i.e. get 25, or boolean if it sees "true" i.e. get true. Currently, I am getting the value as "25" string or "true" as string. I don't have any information about the type of the property before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONPARSER and put a check like this:
if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT), then jsonParser.getIntValue()